# How to specify which property to display when doing console.log to object?

Tags: javascript, properties

When creating an object from constructor, sometimes the result object
have too much property to display when using `console.log`. How can I
specify which property to display?

For example if I have a constructor like this:

```
function Obj(source) {
  this.lines = source.split('\n'); // it can be 1000 lines or even more
}
```

So, If I do:

var obj = new Obj(source);
   console.log(obj);

it will print all those lines to the console. I want to exclude that
property on `console.log`, how?

Comment: _"it can be 1000 lines or even more"_.. Are you talking about `split` data ? Or properties of the `Obj`  ?

Comment: You can specify which properties to print out by doing `console.log(obj.lines)` or `console.log(obj.some_property)`

Comment: @Rayon i'm talking about the object instance which will have that lines as property and which will fill up the output

Comment: What environment are you working in, which `console` are you using?

Comment: @Bergi mainly `nodejs` environment, but I plan to make it works on `browser` too. What I'm looking for is maybe some sort of `__repr__` method in python, which is not `toString`, because `toString` is `__str__` equivalents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On nodejs, [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data) does use [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) to format objects for printing. You can customise it by providing your own `inspect` method on your objects.
Another simple way to prevent a property from being printed to the node console is to make it non-enumerable, as long as that doesn't break your code.

In browsers, with their interactive inspection of logged objects, you usually don't have a problem with too-large objects, as they will be expanded only on request. If you want to control exactly what is printed, your only option is to pass a string to `console.log`, though.

Answer (score 0):

It will by default print all the properties. Unless you specify which property you want to print, it will print all.

If you don't want all the lines then define the property as a function which will give line by line view

```
function Obj(source) {
  this.source = source;
  this.lines = function(){
     return this.source.split('\n');
  } 
}
```

Now if you do `console.log(Obj)` it will only show one line.

Comment: Of course, this fundamentally changes the objects, which I tend to doubt is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using something else, no, you can't reasonably limit what `console.log` shows, and what it shows varies from console implementation to console implementation (or even within the same implementation depending on whether you're showing the console or not when `log` is called).

You may find `console.dir` more useful in this case than `console.log`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir):

> Displays an interactive list of the properties of the specified JavaScript object. The output is presented as a hierarchical listing with disclosure triangles that let you see the contents of child objects.

Of course, that's only really useful if you have an interactive console display (such as in a browser).

Alternately, you could use `console.log(String(obj));` and override the default `toString` to do what you want:

```
Obj.prototype.toString = function() {
    // generate your designer output here
    return desiredOutputString;
};
```

Depending on the console implementation, in some cases, you may not need the `String(...)` part when calling `console.log`, but in most of them you would.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method which will print the object as you like. E.g.

```javascript
Obj.prototype.debug = function () {
  console.log({
    x: this.x,
    y: this.y
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just in the logging that you want to omit the property you could define and immediately call a function in your `console.log` command.

The function could copy the object, remove the `lines` property from it and log the resulting object:

```
function Obj(source) {
  this.lines = source.split('\n'); // it can be 1000 lines or even more
}
var obj = new Obj(source); 
console.log((function(){var copy = Object.assign({}, obj); delete copy.lines; return copy;})())
```