# How to exclude only from console.log a field in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In java there is lombok to not print a field, for example when I don't want to print the user token I use @ToString.Exclude.

```java
import lombok.ToString;

public class TokenResponse {
    @ToString.Exclude
    private String accessToken;
}
```

In javascprit specifically in nodejs, is there anything like that?

Comment: or [How to specify which property to display when doing console.log to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887995/how-to-specify-which-property-to-display-when-doing-console-log-to-object)

Comment: @pilchard this question is not the same as the one posted

Answer (score 0):

You could use [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer#using-groups-to-control-excluded-properties)

```
import { Exclude, classToPlain } from 'class-transformer';

export class TokenResponse {
    @Exclude()
    accessToken: string;
}


console.log(classToPlain(tokenResponseObj));
```

Comment: This solution exclude the field anywhere, I want exclude only `console.log`